# How do I return different strings from each call on a function in C?

Tags: c, malloc, c-strings

I'm a beginner in C, and I'm relatively clueless so I hope someone can help.

I have a method which returns a string depending on what a certain number is.

```
char* getStr(int aNumber)
{
   char *str= malloc(15);
   if(!str)
        return NULL;
   if(aNumber == 0)
        str = "this";
   else if(aNumber== 1)
        str = "that";
   // other "else if" statements
   else
        str= "nope";
return str;
}
```

In another method I have:

```
char *myString = getStr(number1);
  printf("%s", myString);
char *myOtherString = getStr(number2)
  printf("%s", myOtherString);
```

My problem now is that myOtherString is the same as myString. Using strdup() in the getStr() method instead of malloc() also has the same effect while ditching both and just trying to return str without either causes random symbols to be printed out (diamons and question marks).

How can change the getStr() method to allow the output string to be different at each call of the method? Or would I have to somehow free the space allocated to the string after calling it in the other method?

Comment: what's the value of `number1` and `number2` ? and what is the string you are getting back ?

Comment: In this case the call to malloc is extraneous, since you change the pointer to whatever static string it happens to go to through the if-else statements (str = "that" changes str to point to a space in memory containing "that", it doesn't assign "that" to the space str already points to).  Also, you return reg even though it seems you are trying to return str.

Comment: Why `return reg;`?  What is `reg`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you would like is:

```
char* getStr(int aNumber)
{
   char *str= malloc(15);
   if(!str)
        return NULL;
   if(aNumber == 0)
        strcpy(str,"this");
   else if(aNumber== 1)
        strcpy(str, "that");
   // other "else if" statements
   else
        strcpy(str, "nope");
return str;
}
```

isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

C Strings are not fundamental types. They are pointers to characters.

Perhaps a commented version of your function will help.

```
char* getStr(int aNumber)
{
   /* make str point to a new block of uninitialized memory */ 
   char *str= malloc(15);
   if(!str)
        return NULL;


   /* make str point to some other constant array, do not free original allocation */
   if(aNumber == 0)
        str = "this";
   else if(aNumber== 1)
        str = "that";
   // other "else if" statements
   else
        str= "nope";


   return reg;
}
```

Comment: That helped me understand what exactly malloc() does, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
#define STRLEN 15
char* getStr(int aNumber)
{
   char *str= malloc(STRLEN);
   if(!str)
        return NULL;
   if(aNumber == 0)
        snprintf(str, STRLEN, "this");
   else if(aNumber== 1)
        str = snprintf(str, STRLEN, "that");
   // other "else if" statements
   else
        snprintf(str, STRLEN, "nope");

   return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think whether I should return the address of the literal simply.

```
char* getStr(int aNumber){
    if(aNumber == 0)
        return "this";
    else if(aNumber == 1)
        return "that";
    return "nope";
}
```

Turn `const char*` in order to emphasize that the return value can not be changed.

If you want to change the string that you have returned,
You must be freed in this case the caller must copy `strcpy` group in order to use the area secured by `malloc`.

But probably you would not  change the string.